ubuntu 24.04.1 camera- mirror mode
After the last Ubuntu update, Camera app also changed, and now I could not find an option for Flip effect (i.e. mirror effect) when using selfie camera. Any recommendation is appreciated.

The new camera app (GNOME Camera) is not as feature rich as the old one (Cheese Webcam Booth). Install Cheese with the command
sudo apt install cheese

Open Cheese. Click on Effects -> Flip to enable mirror mode.
You can optionally remove the new camera app with the command
sudo apt remove gnome-camera


Solved. Thank you very much!
